# Connecting Remote Oracle 19c Database using Sql Developer

Tags: oracle

I have  installed Oracle 19 c server  in system A. i can access Oracle Pluggable Database using Sql Developer  with local host. but want to access that Database  from System B,in System B  only  installed Sql Develper.

1)what need to Change in System  A  for Remote access?
2)Do need any another  files or Software  other  than sql developer  to Connect Remote Oracle Database
in   System B?
if need which have to install ?

Comment: "How to enable remote aceess to system" is very generic question. Please, check [this help article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to refactor and improve your question. You need to describe the exact problems you have up to now and what steps you have performed. There are lots of information [in the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/admqs/index.html) and bunch of HowTos in the internet.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set up a listener, by default Oracle will use your host name and port 1521.
You need network connectivity from your client (system B) to your server (system A).
You would generally set up a tnsnames.ora file on the client so that you can refer to your database using a tns alias, this isn’t necessary but can be very handy.
In SQL Developer in the client, when you create the connection for the database you would chose your new tnsnames entry or use the basic option and fill out the host etc.

Answer (score 0):

System B should have a way to connect to database on system A. It is the *network*.

As SQL Developer doesn't require Oracle Client, you should be able to connect fairly easy. Though, you have to know certain details about the database itself.

- create new database connection
- enter username and password
- use "Basic" connection type and provide

  - host name (name of the database server; if you don't know it, use its IP address)
  - port (usually 1521)
  - SID or Service name

That should be all.

Comment: Thanks for your  replay, will try  this